# Keep getting "The system cannot find the file specified." when using os.execute

Tags: lua

I keep getting the message

> The system cannot find the file specified.

when trying to copy a file via the `os.execute` and copy command.  I have verified that I am able to copy files via the cmd prompt.

This part works as intended.

```
--  Lines to test copying a file
local Test_Date_Time2 = os.date("%m-%d-%Y_%H_%M_%S")
local File_Name_2 = "..\\\\state_" .. Test_Date_Time .. ".json"
os.execute("copy ..\\\\state.json ".. File_Name_2)
```

However, the following block doesn't.  I tried using `cd` to change the directory, but it leaves me in the same directory as where the Lua file is.

```
local function Backup_JSON ()
  local TURN_NO = 03
  local Current_Date, err_01 = os.date("%m-%d-%Y")
  local Current_Time_02, err_01 = os.date("%H_%M_%S")
  if not Current_Time_02 then
  -- failed to open file, let's display the error
--     trigger.action.outTextForCoalition(2,"\n\nOS not accessible\n" , 15)
--     trigger.action.outTextForCoalition(2,"\n\n" .. err_01 .. "\n", 15)
     print ("\n\nOS not accessible\n")
     print("\n\n" .. err_01 .. "\n")

    else
--      trigger.action.outTextForCoalition(2,"\n\nIn else statement to copy state file\n" , 15)
      print("\n\nIn else statement to copy state file\n")

      local State_Json_Backup = "C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation\\state_T" .. TURN_NO .. "_" .. Current_Date .. "_" .. Current_Time_02 .. ".json "
      local Backup_01, err_03 = os.execute("cd C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation")
      print (State_Json_Backup)
      print (Backup_01)
      local Backup, err_03 = os.execute("dir")

      local Backup, err_02 = os.execute("copy C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation\\state.json" .. State_Json_Backup)
      if err_02 == nil then
      -- do nothing
      else
--      trigger.action.outTextForCoalition(2,"\n\n" .. err_02 .. "\n", 15)
      print("\n\n" .. err_02 .. "\n")
      end    
    end
end

local Backup_01 = Backup_JSON ()
```

I have verified that the file does exist and can copy the file via cmd if I am in that directory.

Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong, or a better way to copy a file to a different name.

Comment: No space between arguments to second copy command? Also, if you really need `cd` or to run multiple commands in the same context, I think it is possible (Windows) to use `cmd /C` (or construct a bat file either separately or a temp bat file as needed).

Answer (score 2):

One of your mistakes is missing quotes around the path containing space

WRONG:

```
local Backup, err_02 = os.execute("copy C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation\\state.json" .. State_Json_Backup)
```

CORRECT:

```
local Backup, err_02 = os.execute('copy "C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation\\state.json" "'..State_Json_Backup..'"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `os.execute` spawns a different [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)), with a different environment. It is a very thin wrapper around the C function [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system).

Changing the working directory in a different process is not going to change the working directory of your current process, or any future process made by `os.execute`.

You can try combining several commands to run in the same shell:

```lua
os.execute('cmd /c cd "C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation" && dir')
```

---

As for your absolute paths, it simply appears you have made a typo, as there will be no separating space between the two arguments you are trying to provide `copy`.

You must also quote your paths if they contain spaces.

Try:

```lua
local source = "C:\\Users\\AKA_Liberation\\Saved Games\\dcs_liberation\\state.json"
os.execute(string.format('copy "%s" "%s"', source, State_Json_Backup))
```

Comment: I tried this and still get the same error.  I also tried you suggested combined cmd to get a directory listing.  That too didn't work.  I'll play around with this some more and see if I can figure it out.